# Switch between screens on combined key press in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I want to switch between two scenes on pressing Ctrl+D and here is my code:
Main Class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //stage.setFullScreen(true);
     //  stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();

          scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
          KeyCombination ctrlD = KeyCodeCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+D");
            //final KeyCombination keyComb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ESCAPE,
           //                                                       KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ctrlD.match(ke)) {
                    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ctrlD);
                   try {
                    Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene2.fxml"));
                    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root1);
                    stage.setScene(scene2);

                   } catch (IOException ex) {

                   }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

It works fine. But when I want to get back from scene2 to scene1, the code doesn't work. Here is my Scene2 controller code:

```
@FXML
private label label1;
  @Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     try{
   Stage stage=(Stage)label1.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.getScene().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        KeyCombination ctrlD = KeyCodeCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+D");
        //final KeyCombination keyComb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ESCAPE,
       //                                                       KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ctrlD.match(ke)) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ctrlD);
                    Parent root;
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene1.fxml"));
                    Stage stage = (Stage) label1.getScene().getWindow();
                    Scene scene=new Scene(root);
                    stage.setScene(scene);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Scene2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    }catch(Exception e){

    }  
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work": what does this mean? Surely this throws a null pointer exception. You should include the stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize()` method is called as part of the load process, i.e. it is invoked during the execution of

```
Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene2.fxml"));
```

Obviously, this happens *before* you add `root1` to a scene, so when you do

```
Stage stage=(Stage)label1.getScene().getWindow();
```

`label1.getScene()` returns `null` and you get a Null Pointer Exception.

Add the event handler to the scene when you create the scene. You can reuse the code if you put it in a method in your application class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // stage.setFullScreen(true);
        // stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();

        registerSceneSwitchHandler(stage, scene, "scene2.fxml");
    }

    private void registerSceneSwitchHandler(Stage stage, Scene scene, String resource) {

      KeyCombination ctrlD = KeyCodeCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+D");
      scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, ke -> {
          if (ctrlD.match(ke)) {
              System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ctrlD);
              try {
                  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resource));
                  Scene newScene = new Scene(root);

                  String returnResource ;
                  if ("scene2.fxml".equals(resource)) {
                      returnResource = "FXMLDocument.fxml";
                  } else {
                      returnResource = "scene2.fxml";
                  }

                  registerSceneSwitchHandler(stage, newScene, returnResource);

                  stage.setScene(scene);

               } catch (IOException ex) {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
          }
      });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And then just remove the event handler from the `initialize()` method.